# Simple gulp task to deploy to google app engine and stream output to console?

Tags: google-app-engine, gulp

Is there a good way to execute the `gcloud` commands to deploy an app to GAE and see the stderr/stdout echoed back at the console? I've tried `gulp-exec` but it seems to batch up the output, dumping only upon completion. It also won't play nicely when trying to preview locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I didn't want to have to use another npm, but loosely inspired by a portion of `gulp-run`, I came up with the following that assumes a 'clean' and 'build' task exists, and also overrides some constants per environment for a `gulp-replace` task that is part of my 'build', the key being the spawn of a subshell and piping its output to the current process's:

```
// gulp deploy [-a dev|staging|prod]
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  var commands = {
    remote: 'gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml -q --set-default --project ',
    local: 'gcloud preview app run app.yaml'
  };

  var environments = {
    dev: {
      app: 'myapp-dev',
    },
    staging: {
      app: 'myapp-staging',
      MY_ENDPOINT: 'https://staging.example.com'
    },
    prod: {
      app: 'myapp',
      MY_ENDPOINT: 'https://example.com'
    }
  };

  var command = commands.local;
  var env = environments[argv.a];
  if (env) {
    command = commands.remote + env.app;
    constantsMap.MY_ENDPOINT = env.MY_ENDPOINT;
  }

  // Now that our constants are configured, kick off the build, then deploy.
  runSequence('clean', 'build', function() {
    var title = util.format('$ %s\n', $.util.colors.blue(command));
    process.stdout.write(title);
    // run the command in its own subshell and pipe the output to our own.
    var subshell = childProcess.spawn('sh', ['-c', command]);
    subshell.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    subshell.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
  });
});
```

This relies on the npms: run-sequence, util, yargs, gulp-load-plugins

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute commands following code snippet will help you. I have wrapped it inside a promise as you are using gulp:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

function executeCommand(command, option) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var args = [option.something,  option.something];
        var ls = cp.spawn(command, args);
        var output = "";

        ls.on('error', function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });

        ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            output += String(data);
            console.log(output)
        });


        ls.on('exit', function (code) {
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve({
                    "output": output
                });
            } else {
                reject(Error(output));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [gulp-gae](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gae) and it seems it works well.

Supported commands are `appcfg.py` and `dev_appserver.py` (in current version). It can be also configured to override some values from the given `app.yaml`.

Comment: The `appcfg.py` and `dev_appserver.py` commands are part of the Launcher, but I've found them also under `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine`.